# I have a JS image slider that I want to go under the fixed menu on scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed

I have a JS image slider that I want to go under the fixed menu on scroll, But [the slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) has to use CSS position:Relative to work. (I can make it go under the nav bar with different position types but then the image slider doesn't work as it should)

How can I keep the slider working but make it go underneath my fixed menu bar?

**Here is the page before scroll:**

```
http://i.imgur.com/JdYL7gx.jpg
```

**Here is the page when the image slider is in front of the nav bar: (I don't want it to be)**

```
http://i.imgur.com/Mt8bLGk.png
```

**here is how the content should be behind the menu:**

```
http://i.imgur.com/6MzVy63.png
```

Comment: did you tried z-index?

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of your slider to a negative number to move it behind the header.

example

```
#slider {
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

Or, set the header to a higher z-index to move it above everything else.

example

```
#header {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

If that doesn't work, share the code so we can help figure it out.